# Does Microsoft LUIS limit your ability to import the entire training set?

Tags: machine-learning, limit, training-data, azure-language-understanding

I have a JSON training set with 4000 utterances, but LUIS only allows me to import 2700 utterances. I don't know which element in LUIS could be causing this (subscription, file too large).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Limitation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdHgE.png)
[Limitation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zskMf.png)

For information about limitation please go to [the information page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-limits#model-limits). If you need more than the limit, contact support. To do so, gather detailed information about your system, go to the LUIS website, and then select Support. If your Azure subscription includes support services, contact Azure technical support.

Comment: I think Google can do this for you.  Check out this link.

https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/08/launching-speech-commands-dataset.html